# 2 Columns and make 1 of it [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

I have 2 Columns like ColumnA and ColumnB. How can I copy/transfer the Values of A into B but dont overwrite my values in B if there are some. So I want to fill the empty fields in column B with values of A.
You can have a better idea of what I need to do in my example!

Thank you!

```
ColumnA  ColumnB      ColumnC
[x]      []           [x]
[]       [y]          [y]
[x]      []     =     [x]
[x]      []           [x]
[]       [y]          [y]
[]       [f]          [f]
[]       [f]          [f]
[]       [f]          [f]
```

Here is the solution. Thank you!

```
update mytable set b = a where b is null and a is not null
```

Comment: use select coalesce(a,b)

Comment: What if both values not empty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to fill the empty fields in column B with values of A

Just:

```
update mytable set b = a where b is null and a is not null
```

The `where` condition filters the query so only records where `b` is `null` and `a` is not are update.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code as well..

```
UPDATE Your_Table
    SET B=CASE WHEN B IS NULL AND A IS NOT NULL THEN A
               ELSE B END
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike zip's comment if you don't want to overwrite the values of column b then use

```
select coalesce(b,a)
```